# Sending packet to interface via multicast

Tags: c++, sockets, multicast

I am trying to send `u_char *packet` (format of specific protocol) over local multicast (IPv6).

These are my steps I have already done:

- Getting interface index via `if_nametoindex(interface.c_str())`, where `interface.c_str()` is string with name of interface
- Getting IPv6 address of interface with `struct ifaddrs *ifc` and `getifaddrs(&ifc)`, where I iterate through `ifc`, compare `ifc->ifa_name` with `interface.c_str()` and checking IPv6 address with `IN6_IS_ADDR_LINKLOCAL(...)`
- Setting socket with `socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)`, setting socket option `SO_REUSEADDR` to 1, `IPV6_MULTICAST_HOPS` to 255 and `IPV6_MULTICAST_IF` to index of interface
- Setting `struct sockaddr_in6` like:

  ```
  struct sockaddr_in6 sa;
  bzero(&sa, sizeof(sa));
  sa.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
  sa.sin6_port = htons(521); //Port RIPng
  sa.sin6_scope_id = interfaceIndex;
  sa.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
  ```
- Binding socket with `bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&sa, sizeof(sa))`
- Sending with `sendto(sock, packet,sizeof(packet) 0, (struct sockaddr*)&sa, sizeof(sa))`

After this, I am trying to listen using wireshark, but no packet of same protocol name is detected.

Where am I doing mistake?

Comment: You need to `sendto()` a specific [multicast address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address), and of course the receiver(s) need to join the multicast group using `setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, ...)`.

Comment: @TypeIA There is no client/server in this application

Comment: I didn't say client or server, but I did say receiver, and in multicast there is always a sender and zero or more receivers. The routing association between the sender and receiver(s) is made via multicast addresses, to which the sender sends and the receivers associate using a socket option.